# Argument Exception was unhandled (Entity Framework, WCF)

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework-4, argumentexception

I have created one basic WCF Service. It thrown an exception at line shown below.

```
  ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyApplication.ITransactionService1));
```

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
Additional information: ServiceHost only supports class service types.**

Comment: What does `ITransactionService1` look like?

Comment: I think you need to pass something like `typeof(MyApplication.ConcreteTransactionService)` It looks like you are getting the type of an interface and not the implementation.

Comment: @mike just an interface that's it.. public interface ITransactionService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [FaultContract(typeof(MyException))]
        [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]
        void InsertData(int id, string name);
    }
        public class MyException
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string ErrorText { get; set; }
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ServiceHost Constructor (Type, Uri[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585489(v=vs.110).aspx) expects a concrete type, not an interface.

Assuming that `ITransactionService1` is your service contract and that you've implemented it in `TransactionService1`:

```
namespace MyApplication
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITransactionService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        int DoSomething(string arg);
    }

    public class TransactionService1 : ITransactionService1
    {

        // Implementation logic
    }
}
```

You would than pass `MyApplication.TransactionService1`:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServieHost(typeof(MyApplication.TransactionService1));
```

Comment: It Worked.. Thank you :)

Comment: this raises `TransactionService1 is not attributed with ServiceContractAttribute` error. And requires to move `ServiceContract` from interface to `TransactionService1` class definition.